# Create a new dataframe based on rows with a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe of transactions which I want to break into two smaller dataframes based on a certain column ("Type"). If "Type" is "S" then add that entire row to the "cust_sell" dataframe, and if "Type" is "P" to the "cust_buy" dataframe. I am using a for loop, but this is only adding the index value to the dataframe. Any help is appreciated!

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
import pandas as pd

filename = (shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL, None, 0)) + '\MSRB T-1_test.xlsx'
wb = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='T1-20062017', index_col=0, header=0)
cust_buy = []
cust_sell = []

# Create a list of customer buys and sells separately
for i in wb.index:
    if wb['Type'][i] == 'S':
        cust_sell.append([i])
    elif wb['Type'][i] == 'P':
        cust_buy.append([i])
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample of your data that you're working with?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You do not need to write loops. You can do it easily with pandas.

Assuming your dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd  

mainDf = pd.DataFrame()
mainDf['Type'] = ['S', 'S', 'S', 'P', 'P', 'S', 'P', 'S']
mainDf['Dummy'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

To create dataframe for S and P types, you can just do this:

```
cust_sell = mainDf[mainDf.Type == 'S']
cust_buy = mainDf[mainDf.Type == 'P']
```

cust_sell output:

```
  Type  Dummy
0    S      1
1    S      2
2    S      3
5    S      6
7    S      8
```

cust_buy output:

```
  Type  Dummy
3    P      4
4    P      5
6    P      7
```

Answer (score 3):

Like @trollster said, it is indeed better to create dataframes for cust_sell and cust_buy. But let's understand what is not working with your code. When you do:

```
for i in wb.index
```

it means i will take the values of wb.index. And when you print wb.index, you get:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
```

Meaning i will take the values 1,2,3 ...
So when you do:

```
cust_sell.append([i])
```

what you are doing is adding to the list_cust_sell a list with inside a single element, i (an integer).
If you want to add the entire row, you should use:

```
cust_sell.append(list(wb.loc[i,:]))
```

You will end up with a list of lists, each one containing a row

Answer (score 2):

Using `dict` + `groupby` you can create a dictionary of dataframes. This solution does not require you to manually specify all unique types and is more easily extendable than a manual loop.

Data from @trollster.

```
res = dict(tuple(mainDf.groupby('Type')))

{'P':   Type  Dummy
      3    P      4
      4    P      5
      6    P      7,
 'S':   Type  Dummy
      0    S      1
      1    S      2
      2    S      3
      5    S      6
      7    S      8}
```